# Want create a new list from existing list using if else statement

Tags: python, list, if-statement, jupyter-notebook, list-comprehension

> I want to create a new list using existing list "dta", where i do not want a value for "banana" but a numeric for others.
>   desired list is below:

```
[1,3,4,5,6]
```

but when i am trying to print of my final list "d" then i get only single value.

```
dta=list(["apple","banana","pine","cucumber","Guava","Coconut"])

d=[]
def cont_list(x):

for i in x:
    if i=="banana":
        continue
if i=="pine":
    d.append(3)

elif i=="apple":
    d.append(1)

elif i=="cucumber":
    d.append(4)
elif i=="Guava":
    d.append(5)
else:
    d.append(6)

return d   

cont_list(dta)
print(d)
```

Comment: the indentation here looks botched, can you please check and fix?

Comment: Your code gave me `[1, 3, 4, 5, 6]` when I fixed the indentation. Is that the expected result? note that `if i` won't throw an error when outside the `for` loop.

Comment: note to other editors, please do not fix the indentation on this question yourself, you may accidentally get rid of the error in OP's code. This is most likely a case of bad indentation. Note to OP, please edit the question and show your exact code.

Comment: @Guy did you use my code and got the desired list? can you suggest correction?

Comment: @SanchitAluna Your code works when properly indent. There is nothing else to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with list comprehension:

```
dta = ["apple","banana","pine","cucumber","Guava","Coconut"]

d = [idx for idx in range(1,len(dta)+1) if dta[idx-1] != "banana"]
print (d)
```

in function:

dta=list(["apple","banana","pine","cucumber","Guava","Coconut"])

```
def cont_list(x):
    dta = ["apple","banana","pine","cucumber","Guava","Coconut"]
    d = [idx for idx in range(1,len(dta)+1) if dta[idx-1] != "banana"]
    return d
print (cont_list(dta))
```

output:

```
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

NOTE: your code will be ok if you fix INDENTION:

```
d=[]
def cont_list(x):

    for i in x:
        if i=="banana":
            continue
        if i =="pine":
            d.append(3)

        elif i=="apple":
            d.append(1)

        elif i=="cucumber":
            d.append(4)
        elif i=="Guava":
            d.append(5)
        else:
            d.append(6)
    return d

cont_list(dta)
print(d)
```

or you can do it like:

```
d=[]
def cont_list(x):

    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i]=="banana":
            continue
        else:
            d.append(i+1)
    return d

cont_list(dta)
print(d)
```

Comment: you're welcome. I'm glad I helped :) in general dont forget upvote or accept an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to use the index of the items (plus one)... This can be done with a simple list comprehension:

```
dta = ["apple","banana","pine","cucumber","Guava","Coconut"]
d = [dta.index(e) + 1 for e in dta if e != 'banana']
```

Or with `enumerate` (which I would expect to be marginally faster in case of large lists):

```
dta = ["apple","banana","pine","cucumber","Guava","Coconut"]
d = [i for i, e in enumerate(dta, 1) if e != 'banana']
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer but Can we do this with if else loop in function?

Comment: @SanchitAluna 1. You can fix the indentation as others explained. 2. You change the list comprehensions I showed to a function